# Why does touchesBegan stop working when UIImageView in placed inside a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, uiscrollview, uiimageview

```
UIView -> UIImageView
```

I know I have things somewhat working ok since I can tap on my `UIImageView` and see an `NSLog()` statement in my `touchesBegan` method.

.

```
UIView -> UIScrollView -> UIImageView
```

I drag that same `UIImageView` into a `UIScrollView` and `touchesBegan` no longer gets called when I tap on my `UIImageView`.  (I haven't changed anything else.  All the same connections, methods, and code remains unchanged.)

Why does `touchesBegan` no longer work?  And what can I do to get it working again?

Answer (score 4):

Add uitapgesture to get event

Code is

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *ges11=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Handeltap:)];
  [imagename addGestureRecognizer:ges11];
```

Create one action name "Handeltap" U will get called there.

Answer (score 4):

by default `UIImageView` don't handle user gestures.
set `UIImageView` instance's `userInteractionEnabled` to YES

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the documentation for UIScrollView.

> Because a scroll view has no scroll bars, it must know whether a touch signals an intent to scroll versus an intent to track a subview in the content. To make this determination, it temporarily intercepts a touch-down event by starting a timer and, before the timer fires, seeing if the touching finger makes any movement. If the timer fires without a significant change in position, the scroll view sends tracking events to the touched subview of the content view. If the user then drags their finger far enough before the timer elapses, the scroll view cancels any tracking in the subview and performs the scrolling itself. Subclasses can override the `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:`, `pagingEnabled`, and `touchesShouldCancelInContentView:` methods (which are called by the scroll view) to affect how the scroll view handles scrolling gestures.

I'd also recommend reading the [Scroll View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html).